# Magento 2 Simple jQuery Example

Tags: magento2, javascript, magento-2.0, jquery

I was wondering if anyone could provide a simple jQuerying hello world example in Magento 2. I have read the documentation on requireJS and the Magento 2 documentation and I am still struggling.

This is what I have in my script tag in my PHTML file.

```
require([ 'jquery'], function($){


    $( "p" ).click(function() {
        alert("Test!");
    });

});
```

Comment: The script above should work, what exact issue are you having? Did you run `bin/magento setup:upgrade`?

Answer (score 12):

Using jQuery simple  example:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    require([ 'jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){ $(document).ready(function($) {
   alert("test");
}); });</script>
```

for your case:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    require([ 'jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){ $( "#yourid" ).click(function() {
    alert("Test!");
}); });</script>
```

Comment: You don't need to require jquery/uj unless you need to use it.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
    require([ 'jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){ 
 $( "#checkoutnext" ).click(function() { 
  alert("Test!");
 });
 });
 </script>


Not Working In Checkout What to DO ?

Answer (score 7):

You can also use *domready!±* in the require statement. That will mean your code won't execute until the dom is ready, same as using document ready.

```
require([
    'jquery',
    'domReady!'// wait for dom ready
], function ($) {

    $( "p" ).click(function() {
        alert("Test!");
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

**create requirejs-config**

**app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/Mageplaza_LayeredNavigation/requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            customjs: 'Mageplaza_LayeredNavigation/js/custom_layerd'
        }
    }};
```

**add js file**

**app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/Mageplaza_LayeredNavigation/web/js/custom_layerd.js**

```
require([
    'jquery'
], function ($) {
    'use strict';
    //start the logic like
    $('.plus').parent().hasClass("opened");
    
});
```

**use in phtml file**
**app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/Mageplaza_LayeredNavigation/templates/layer/category_filter.phtml**

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "*": {
        "Mageplaza_LayeredNavigation/js/custom_layerd": {}
    }
}
</script>
```